# Как настроить Routing на Laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, route

Кто знает помогите с проблемой
как мне настроить Route и Controller

```
Route::get('/{lang?}/{city?}/{category}/{post}', [PostController::class, 'post'])->name('view');
```

чтобы запись была доступно по ссылке

```
https://example.com/ru/city/category/post-slug
https://example.com/ru/category/post-slug
https://example.com/city/category/post-slug
https://example.com/category/post-slug
```

чтобы работал таким образом если указан язык то будет показываться по языку если нет то просто по тому языку который идет по умолчанию
а если нет города тоже чтобы показывал но тоже без города
я настраиваю, Controller c параметрами, если убрать со ссылке {lang} или {city} то все смешается